# Make Jenkins build specific branch after git post commit hook

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using Atlassian's Stash which is hosted by myself. There I have a git post commit hook, which triggers my Jenkins machine. Currently this is working for pull requests (every time a pull request is made/updated, the hook will invoke Jenkins which will build). For this to work I use the Source Code Management plugin, and there I have `pr` as name and `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` as the refspec. I have also chosen the branch to build from, which is `develop`.

Now I want to be able to locally create a release branch, for instance `release/1.0`, add some changes to it. Then I want to push this to my Stash server, which will trigger the hook and let Jenkins build the release branch. My problem is that the job is run each time a commit happens, on any branch.

How can I make this only happen when I push commits to my release branch? Note that I want to have more release branches in the future, so there might be `release/1.0`, `release/1.1` and `release/2.0` and so on, so I cannot hard code any branch name in Jenkins (I want to have this dynamic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, a colleague of mine helped me solve this problem. We fixed it by leaving the name field empty, and in refspec we put in `+refs/heads/release/*:refs/remotes/origin/release/*`, and as branch to build we put in `origin/release/*`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger only on commits to your release branch, it should suffice to change your refspec in the Source Code Management plugin to `+refs/pull/*:refs/remotes/origin/release/*`.

Comment: You would think so, but I pushed a branch named *test_branch_to_remove* and then the job started for this branch, when it should do nothing.